# React POST 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a registration form using API Fetch in react but when I try to post, I get an error POST (the URL) 422 (Unprocessable Entity). I tried to run the URL in postman and it accepts the registration. below is my handle submit to perform the fetch API POST

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = {email: email, password: password, password_confirmation: password_confirmation}

  fetch(`${baseURL}//api/v1/auth/`, {
    method:'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Content-Length": "<calculated when request is sent>",
      "Host": "<calculated when request is sent>",
      "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  }).then(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp)
    alert('Form Submitted')
    return resp.json();
  })
}
```

Comment: Two suggestions: 1- drop the `content-length` and `host` headers. 2- look at the network tab in your browser and see what is actually being sent.

Comment: In addition to GregHNZ's suggestion, try to debug or print the data variable right before its send out to check if email/password and others are what you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to switch to axios. Thank you guys especially GregHNZ for the number 2 suggestion. I found out there that I am not sending a valid email address. I was sending test@stack.c which should be test@stack.com

```
const createPost = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = {email: email, password: password, password_confirmation: password_confirmation}

  axios
    .post(baseURL, data)
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: this is a wrong answer.